# mixing generic and non-generic collections in java

Tags: generics

I am facing a dilemma in mixing of generic and non-generic collection.
For example:
This is new java 5/6 generic code.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);

Alpha a = new Alpha();
a.insert(list);

for (Integer integer : list) {
System.out.println(integer);      //will get classCastException
}
```

Non-generic legacy code

```
public class Alpha {
    public void insert(List list) { 
    list.add(new String("50"));
    }
}
```

I know at time of i will get classCastException at runtime.
But i want to print all the elements of list even after adding Strings/Dogs.
Can someone suggest me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - you just need to avoid the compiler inserting a cast for you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Nice strongly-typed list...
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(5);

        // Now abuse it...
        List raw = list;
        raw.add("Bad element");        

        // Don't use the "integer" part, effectively...
        for (Object x : list) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler isn't casting each element to `Integer`, so we're okay.

**However** - if you need to do this, it indicates that your code is fundamentally a bit broken. You'd be far better off fixing `Alpha` to avoid adding unexpected items to the list.